# How to solve assignment problem using cycle cancelling algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, max-flow

I am trying to solve the following problem on hackeearth.

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/minimum-cost-maximum-flow/tutorial/

I was trying to implement the cycle cancelling algorithm using the following tutorial on top coder.

https://www.topcoder.com/community/competitive-programming/tutorials/minimum-cost-flow-part-one-key-concepts/

As cycle cancelling algorithm wants me to find negative cycles and augment the flow along those cycles, I am using modified bellman ford algorithm described in the link below for augmenting the flow along negative cycles.
https://algosdotorg.wordpress.com/87-2/

Still I am not able to get the correct answer for the problem.

Here is the full code implementation for the problem

```
package graphs;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class CycleCancellingAlgo {

    public static final int INF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    static class Edge {
        int u;
        int v;
        int f;
        int cap;
        int cost;
        int r;

        Edge (int u, int v, int f, int cap, int cost, int r) {
            this.u = u;
            this.v = v;
            this.f = f;
            this.cap = cap;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.r = r;
        }
    }

    static void addEdge (List <Edge> [] g, int u, int v, int cap, int cost) {
        Edge a = new Edge(u, v, 0, cap, cost, g[v].size());
        Edge b = new Edge(v, u, 0, 0, -cost, g[u].size());
        g[u].add(a);
        g[v].add(b);
    }

    static boolean bfs (List<Edge> [] g, int s, int t, int [] l) {
        Arrays.fill(l, -1);
        l[s] = 0;
        LinkedList <Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.addLast(s);

        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            int u = q.pollFirst();
            for(Edge e : g[u]) {
                if(l[e.v] == -1 && e.f < e.cap) {
                    l[e.v] = l[u] + 1;
                    q.addLast(e.v);
                }
            }
        }
        return l[t] != -1;
    }


    static int sendFlow(List <Edge> [] g, int s, int t, int [] l, int f) {
        if(s == t)
            return f;

        for(Edge e : g[s]) {
            if(l[s] + 1 == l[e.v] && e.f < e.cap) {
                int f1 = Math.min(f, e.cap - e.f);
                int f2 = sendFlow(g, e.v, t, l, f1);
                if(f2 > 0) {
                    e.f += f2;
                    g[e.v].get(e.r).f -= f2;
                    return f2;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static void maxFlow(List <Edge> [] g, int s, int t, int V) {
        int l [] = new int [V + 1];
        while(bfs(g, s, t, l))
            while(sendFlow(g, s, t, l, INF) != 0);
    }

    static int bellmanFord (List <Edge> [] g, int V, int s, List <Edge> edgesInCycle) {

        int c [] = new int [V + 1];
        Arrays.fill(c, INF);
        c[s] = 0;

        Edge [] pre = new Edge [V + 1];

        for(int i = 1; i <= V - 1; ++i) {
            for(int u = 1; u <= V; ++u) {
                for(Edge e : g[u]) {
                    if(e.f < e.cap && c[u] != INF && c[e.v] > c[u] + e.cost) {
                        c[e.v] = c[u] + e.cost;
                        pre[e.v] = e;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Edge foundCycle = null;

        for(int u = 1; u <= V; ++u) {
            for(Edge e : g[u]) {
                if(e.f < e.cap && c[u] != INF && c[e.v] > c[u] + e.cost){
                    foundCycle = e;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(foundCycle == null)
            return -1;

        Edge startEdge = foundCycle;
        Edge preEdge;
        Map<Edge, Integer> edgesInCycleMap = new HashMap<>();

        while(true) {
            preEdge = pre[startEdge.u];
            if(edgesInCycleMap.get(preEdge) != null)
                break;
            edgesInCycle.add(preEdge);
            edgesInCycleMap.put(preEdge, 1);
            startEdge = preEdge;
        }

        int idx = edgesInCycle.indexOf(preEdge);

        for(int i = 0; i < idx; ++i)
            edgesInCycle.remove(i);

        int m = INF;

        for(Edge e : edgesInCycle)
            m = Math.min(m, e.cap - e.f);


        return m;
    }

    static void saturate (List <Edge> [] g, List <Edge> edgesInCycle, int m) {
        for(Edge e : edgesInCycle) {
            e.f += m;
            g[e.v].get(e.r).f -= m;
        }
    }

    static int cost (List <Edge> [] g, int V) {
        int c = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= V; ++i) {
            for(Edge e : g[i]) {
                if(e.f > 0)
                    c += e.f * e.cost;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    static void print (List <Edge> [] g) {
        for (int i = 1; i < g.length; ++i){
            for(Edge e : g[i]) {
                System.out.println(e.u + " " + e.v + " " + e.f + " " + e.cost + " " + e.cap);
            }
        }
    }

    static void tG (List <Edge> [] tG, List <Edge> [] g, int N, int s, int t) {
       for(int i = 1; i <= 2 * N; ++i)
           tG[i].addAll(g[i]);

       for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
           addEdge(tG, s, i, 1, 0);
           addEdge(tG, i + N, t, 1, 0);
       }

    }

    static int b (List <Edge> [] g, int V, List <Edge> e) {
        int m;
        for(int i = 1; i <= V; ++i)
            if((m = bellmanFord(g, V, i, e)) != -1)
                return m;
        return -1;
    }

    static void minCostFlow (List <Edge> [] g, int N) {

        List <Edge> [] tG = new ArrayList [2 * N + 3];

        for(int i = 1; i <= 2 * N + 2; ++i)
            tG[i] = new ArrayList<>();

        int s = 2 * N + 1;
        int t = 2 * N + 2;

        tG(tG, g, N, s, t);

        maxFlow(tG, s, t, 2 * N + 2);

        List <Edge> edgesInCycle = new ArrayList<>();
        int m;
        while((m = b(g, 2 * N, edgesInCycle)) != -1) {
            saturate(g,edgesInCycle, m);
            edgesInCycle.clear();
        }



        System.out.println(cost(g, 2 * N));

    }


    public static void main (String [] args) {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
            int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            List <Edge> [] g = new ArrayList [2 * N + 1];



            for(int i = 1; i <= 2 * N; ++i)
                g[i] = new ArrayList<>();

            String l;
            for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
                l = br.readLine();
                for(int j = N + 1; j <= 2 * N; ++j)
                    addEdge(g, i, j, 1, Integer.parseInt(l.split(" ")[j - N - 1]));
            }

            minCostFlow(g, N);

        }catch(Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Could some one please help me in figuring out what is wrong with my implementation of cycle cancelling algorithm.